# Caliburn 3 does not see a View

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I've been using Caliburn 1.6 for a couple of years.
Now, I'm trying to wire up the project with Caliburn 3.
And it's clear that something has changed, since then.

I've set up the IoC-container. All the things are correct.
Caliburn says that it does not see a View. 
Assembly in which Views reside is added in the `SelectAssemblies` method in the bootstrapper. So, I decided to download sources and debug a little bit, since I know what is going on in Caliburn under the hood.
And I've noticed that it does not get exported types (publicly defined Views) from the Views assembly. This happens because it sees the `Core` compile-flag and thus it requires Views to inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
If I remove this flag from the build options, Caliburn projects don't compile successfully.

If I add Caliburn through NuGet and inherit Views from INPC, then Caliburn stops to say that it can't find Views, but nothing gets rendered. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What IoC framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using Castle Windsor

Comment: I thought maybe you are using SimpleInjector, because there was a breaking change there as well, but apparently you are having a different problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I called to StartRuntime from the constructor of the bootstrapper. The right way is to call Initialize.

Comment: @MikeCaron Glad to hear it)))